# Send a dict from js to views: return querydict who bursts my dict

Tags: django

I have a dict that I would like to send but I receive it in the form of a querydict whose content is no longer in the same form as the dict sent.

How can i have an object that i can manipulate simply ? I would like to add the elements in a database so I should do a for loop and add by index (key1, key2) but I can't get the real length when i do len(request.POST) it return 5.

**.js**

```
function sendData(event){
    const res = { 0:{"val1": 1, "val2":2}, 1:{"val1": 3, "val2":4}}
    ...
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: {
            "result": res,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        ...
    }) }
```

**views.py**

```
def view1(request):
     print(request.POST)

$ <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...'], 'result[0][val1]': ['1'], 'result[0][val2]': ['2'], 'result[1][val1]': ['3'], 'result[1][val2]': ['4']}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an iterable that will be easier to work with by calling [`lists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists) on the querydict.
You'll get a list of two element tuples. The first element being the key of your dict and the second the list of all values associated with the key.

```
for key, values in request.POST.lists():
   ...
```

Comment: I can't understand how manipulate this object. I do  `request.POST.lists()` it returns `<dict_itemiterator object at 0x0000018991073650> `  then i do `request.POST.lists().values()` it returns `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: I edited my answer, you do not need to call `.values()`